# Is it ever a good idea to store an array as a field value, or store array values as records?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

In my application I've got "articles" (similar to posts/tweets/articles) that are tagged with descriptive predefined tags: i.e "difficult", "easy", "red", "blue", "business" etc

These available tags are stored in a table, call it "tags" that contains all available tags.

Each article can be tagged with multiple tags, editable through a custom admin interface.

It could be tempting to simply bundle the tags for each entity into a stringified array of the IDs of each tag and store it alongside the article record in my "articles" table:

```
id | title | author | tags
---+-------+--------+-------------
1  | title | TG     | "[1,4,7,12]"
```

though I'm sure this is a bad idea for a number of reasons, is there ever a reasonable reason to do the above?

Comment: I don't know PostgreSQL but, as it seems to support XML, storing your tags list as an XML string could bring substantial benefits over a simple delimited list.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you should read about [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and decide for yourself. In short though, there are a number of issues with your proposal, but you may decide you can live with them.

The most obvious are:

1. What if an additional tag is added to row(1)? Do you have to first parse, check if it's already present then update the row to be `tags.append(newTag)`.
2. Worse still deleting a tag? Search tags, is present, re-create tags.
3. What if a tag is to change name - some moderation process, perhaps?
4. Worse again, what about dfferent people specifying a tag-name differently - it'd be hard to rationalise.
5. What if you want to query data based on tags? Your query becomes far more complex than it would need to be.
6. Presentation: The client has to parse the tag in order to use it. What about the separator field? Change that and all clients have to change.

In short, all of these operations become harder and more cumbersome. Normalization is designed to overcome such issues. Probably the only reason for doing what you say, IMO, is that you're capturing the data as a one-off and it's informational only - that is, makes sense to a user but not to a system per-se. This is kind of like saying it's probably best avoided (again, IMO).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like you want to have a separate table that stores tags and holds a foreign key which relates the tag records back to their parent record in the articles table (this is referred to as "normalizing" the database structure).

Doing it like you have suggested by cramming the tags into one field may seem to make sense now, but it will prove to be difficult to maintain and difficult/time consuming to pull the values out efficiently as your application grows in size or the amount of data grows a lot larger.

I would say that there are very few reasons to do what you have suggested, given how straightforward it is to create another table and setup a relationship to link keys between the two tables to maintain referential integrity.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree that it *CAN* be a good idea. I am a strong advocate of storing tags in the database as a single delimited list of strings.

BUT: The reason that I agree is that I like to use Azure Search API to index these types of data, so the query to do a lookup based on tags is not done via SQL. (using the Azure search API service is not necessary, but In my experience you will get much better performance and scalability by using a search index that is outside of the database.)

> If you primary query language will be SQL (relational based queries)
>   then you are better off creating a child table that has a row for each
>   tag, otherwise you will wear a performance hit when your query has to
>   perform a logic on each value to split it for analysis.

Tagging is a concept that we use to get around relational data or hierarchical mapping, so to get the best performance do no try to use these relational concepts to query the tags. It is often best implemented in NoSQL data storage because they don't try to use the database to process the search queries.

I encourage you to store the data as a delimited string, and use an external indexing service to provide search and insights into your data. This is a good trade off between CRUD data access performance attempts to manage the data and indexes to optimise for searching. Sure you can optimise the DB and the search queries to make it work in SQL but it can take effort to get it right.

Once your user base hits large volumes and you need to support multiple concurrent searches without affecting update performance you will find that external indexing is an awesome investment in your time now, to save you time and resources later.

Comment: A comma-separated string is certainly NOT the way to go here. There are a range of GisT/GIN-based indexes in PostgreSQL that will search either an array of ints or text tokens just fine.

Comment: An array of ints or text tokens... which are somehow delimited right? My point is that what ever format you choose to use, it is perfectly valid to store the data in a single field in the DB if your query language supports an optimised way of accessing the data. So to me it sounds like you are actually agreeing :) I am happy with comma because my chosen index methods can process comma delimited strings faster than other structures in this single field format.

Comment: This isn't really the forum for discussions, but no not delimited - stored as the appropriate structured type. Mashing it all into text is a last resort. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype.html

Comment: Point taken :) In my ignorance I did not realise this question was specifically tagged for PostgreSQL