# If I have tblBookInfo (bookId, title... etc.) and I want it to have categories column, what is the best way to do it?

Tags: sql-server, relationship, categories, join

If I have tblBookInfo (bookId, title... etc.) and I want it to have categories column, what is the best way to do it?

### Option 1

categories table will have FK related to bookId like this

tblBookInfo

```
bookId     title
1          test title
2          test title 2
```

tblCategories

```
bookId     name
1          Science fiction
1          Mystery
1          Horror
2          Science fiction
2          Mystery
```

*In this case, category name will be repeated many times and it's ugly*

### Option 2

Store an array of int in btlBookInfo like this

tblBookInfo

```
bookId     title          categories
1          test title     [1,2,3]
2          test title 2   [1,2]
```

*I heard storing array in a column is not a best practice as asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34994964/is-it-ever-a-good-idea-to-store-an-array-as-a-field-value-or-store-array-values)*

### Option 3

Leave the categories table as it is like this

tblCategories

```
id     name
1      Science finction
2      Mystery
3      Horror
```

And add a FK to tblBookInfo like this

tblBookInfo

```
bookId     title          categoryId
1          test title     1
2          test title 2   2
```

Finally, add another table that links these to tables like this

tblCategoryAdapter

```
bookId     categoryId
1          1
1          2
1          3
2          1
2          2
```

*Now I don't have to repeat the category name but I don't think if it is normal*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be fairly straightforward to determine how to architect the database by a thorough understanding of the problem domain, examining the entities you've discovered, and being sure you understand the relationships between those entities.

Here you have two entities: Book and Category. It appears that two rules you've already determined from your problem domain are:

1. A Book can belong to 1 or more Categories
2. A Category can have 1 or more Books

The above can be simplified into "There exists a many-to-many relationship between Books and Categories."

In classic SQL database engines it is not possible to implement a many-to-many relationship directly between two tables.  It must be implemented by a 1-to-many or 0-to-many relationship between each of the two original tables with and a new table that is used to cross-reference the rows of the original two tables. Such tables are variously called "cross-reference table", "relationship table", "join table" or "intersection table".

In your case, it appears that you need a table to cross-reference Books to Categories, and vice versa.

This might be diagrammed (somewhat poorly as it's hard to diagram in Stack Overflow) as:

```
Book <----- Book_Category -----> Category
```

or

```
Book -1-----M- Book_Category -M-----1- Category
```

So you n eed to introduce that Book_Category table (with whatever name you choose), which contains a foreign key to the Book table and a foreign key to the Category table.

You might do it like this:

**tblBookInfo**

```
CREATE TABLE tblBookInfo(
    BookId int not null,
    Name varchar(50) not null,
    CONSTRAINT PK_tblBookInfo PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (BookId)
);
```

**tblCategory**

```
CREATE TABLE tblCategory(
    CategoryId int not null,
    Name varchar(50) not null,
    CONSTRAINT PK_tblCategory PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (CategoryId)
);
```

**tblBookInfo_Category**

```
CREATE TABLE tblBookInfo_Category(
    BookId int not null FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tblBook(BookId),
    CategoryId int not null FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tblCategory(CategoryId)
);
```

Comment: Then... option 3 is my best shot?

Comment: I'll expand my answer.